# What exactly is called "embedding" in dimensionality reduction?

Tags: terminology, dimensionality-reduction, manifold-learning

In the following slide I do not understand the definition of the term *embedding*.

In the third paragraph, it says it is a mapping from low-dim. to high-dim, but in the last paragraph it suggests that it is a map from high-dim. to low-dim. (which sounds quite natural to me).

Is the definition (third paragraph) incorrect?
[image: Manifold and embedding slide]

Comment: I can't see your image/slide.

Comment: Weird, I see it. It can also be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT05O.png

Comment: The last paragraph clearly states it is discussing situations where the method does not create a manifold and so no embedding either. There is no conflict

Comment: Perhaps you are right. I was disturbed by the word "but". I interpreted that sentence as: they create a manifold, but they do not create an embedding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, I found on these slides an example:

> The mapping $x = W z$ defines an embedding of an $m$-dimensional manifold in $p$-dimensional space

where $x$ is the original data. Moreover, now I understand why it is like this: the low-dim. space is embedded into the high-dim. space though an embedding (given a low-dim. vector, one applies the **embedding** to obtain the **embedded** version of the low-dim. vector into the high-dim. space).

Answer (score -1):

While learning about a concept , never go with only a single source , try and cross validate with different texts , to confirm any hypothesis or definition.

This snippet itself is not comprehensive enough , and there should be more text supporting as to , what exactly embedding of manifold really is , and how well it should be understood to distinguish the so called "method" in this text.

Generally , embedding methods even in non-linear , or higher dimension can be visualized as regularization or decision trees.