# What is embedding? (in the context of dimensionality reduction)

Tags: pca, terminology, dimensionality-reduction, multidimensional-scaling, embeddings

In the context of dimensionality reduction one often uses word **embedding**, which seems to me a [rather technical mathematical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding), which rather stands out compared to the rest of the discussion, which in case of PCA, MDS and similar methods is just the basic linear algebra.

Yet, I would rather avoid using/interpreting this term too loosely. So, what *embedding* really is: the low-dimensional *subspace* hidden within a bigger one? The *projections of the data vectors* onto this subspace? The *projection operator* mapping the higher-dimensional space onto the lower-dimensional one, as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473124/what-is-the-difference-between-embedding-in-pure-math-and-embedding-in-ml) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366186/what-exactly-is-called-embedding-in-dimensionality-reduction)? Something else?

Thank you for clarifications and examples.

Comment: @Tim Thank you. In principle, I have now my question answered. However my formulation is different from those given elsewhere (is embedding a subspace OR a projection OR and operation/function), so you might consider reopening it for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 3):

The word is used ambiguously, e.g. this quote from [Google crash course on machine learning](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/embeddings/video-lecture) says *[my comments in square brackets]*:

> An embedding is a relatively low-dimensional space *[subspace]* into which you can
> translate high-dimensional vectors. Embeddings make it easier to do
> machine learning on large inputs like sparse vectors representing
> words. Ideally, an embedding captures some of the semantics of the
> input by placing semantically similar inputs close together in the
> embedding space *[projection]*. An embedding can be learned and reused across models *[mapping]*.

Depending on context, it's best that you make it precise if you are talking about *embedding layer* in neural network (the function), or the generated *embeddings matrix*, or *embeddings* in short (the projections), or you could directly say that you are taking about *embedding space*. Usually the word *embedding* would be used to describe the projection of a word into the latent vector, e.g. "embeddings were created using BERT model".